# Cakephp's beforeSave() not retaining new data using $model::save()

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, callback, requesthandler

When i do `debug($this->data)` on SalasController `reservar()` method, $data from json is ok, but when i do `this->Sala->save($this->data)`, and try `debug($data)` on `beforeSave()` return that:

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: FormataDataBehavior::$data [APP\Model\Behavior\FormataDataBehavior.php, line 52]
\app\Model\Behavior\FormataDataBehavior.php (line 52)
null
```

SalasController.php

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class SalasController extends AppController {

public $components = array('RequestHandler');

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('listar', 'reservar');
    $this->RequestHandler->addInputType('json', array('json_decode', true));
}
    public function reservar() {
    $this->Sala->save($this->data); //no conditions just for debugging.
}
```

Model Sala.php

```
class Sala extends AppModel {

public $useTable = 'agenda';
public $actsAs = array(
    'FormataData' => array('dia')
);
```

Behavior

```
class FormataDataBehavior extends ModelBehavior {

// Armazena os campos do model a serem formatados.
public $campos;

//Inicializa o behavior
public function setup(Model $model, $settings = array()) {
    if (!empty($settings)) {
        $this->campos[$model->name] = $settings;
    } else {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedException('Campos data não informados na declaração do behavior');
    }
}

public function beforeSave(Model $model, $options = array()) {
    parent::beforeSave($model, $options);
    debug($this->data); //trying show data, but is !isset... =/
    die();
}
```

MyJs

```
function adicionarReserva() {
var dadosForm = {Sala: {}};
$.each($("#form-reservas").serializeArray(), function(index, value) {
    dadosForm.Sala[value.name] = value.value;
});
$.post("/intracake/Salas/reservar.json", dadosForm)
        .done(function(data) {
            sysMsg(data.html);
            atualizaTabelas();
        });
}
```

Comment: `FormataDataBehavior` is a behaviour, not a model, so I think you should do `$model->data` instead of `$this->data`.

Comment: `$data = $model->read();` ?

Comment: `$model->data` (I edited my comment), `data` is a public attribute of Model according to CakePHP api so you can access it from anywhere.

Comment: So, i will post an answer... you can check if is a good practice? I posting the code.

Comment: I not understand why cake docs refer `$model::$data`, just `$this->data` inside `beforeSave()` callback.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave

Comment: Because you're looking at the documentation for the `Model` class, not the `ModelBehaviour` class.

Comment: So, my answer is correct? Thinking about good practices? I can pass `&$model` like an reference param, for edit some fieds in `beforeSave()`?

Answer (score 0):

My beforeSave after @Holt tips;

```
public function beforeSave(Model $model, $options = array()) {
    parent::beforeSave($model, $options);
    $this->formataBeforeSave($model);
    return true;
}

public function formataBeforeSave(Model &$model, $padrao = 'Y-m-d') {
    foreach ($this->campos[$model->name] as $campo) {
        if (isset($model->data[$model->name][$campo]) && !empty($model->data[$model->name][$campo])) {
            $model->data[$model->name][$campo] = $this->converte($model, $model->data[$model->name][$campo], $padrao);
        }
    }
}
```